# Controlling a bump map of a shader with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I'm fairly new to blender and geometry nodes and the way attributes are shared across geometry nodes to shader nodes has me cross eyed a bit. But here is the problem I'm trying to solve:
[image]
I'm trying to great a node system that lets me draw stitch lines, using curves, on the surface of a mesh. So far that's working great! I draw a curve onto a surface and apply my geonodes to that curve and I have stitches that can be procedurally modified.
[image]
And the way the stitches work is I'm just telling the curve to dip down at set intervals with a "Set Position" node applied to the curve.

BUT.... I would like for the bump map of the material of the surface being stitched onto, to be impacted by where the stitch "punctures" that surface. So that I can create a realistic look of the threads impacting the surface it's on. The material would need to be impacted at these points...[image]

NOTE: I know this can me done to the surface mesh within geo nodes! but to displace so many points along a surface would be super expensive computationally, which is why modifying the textures bump map would be way more efficient... i think.

is there a way to do this??

Comment: You could isolate/create points from the spline at the punctures, then store a named Distance attribute using a Geometry Proximity, and use it in your shader:  https://i.imgur.com/sQ1Gs52.png It relies on mesh density though. I'm not really good with shaders, so I don't know if it's possible to create mesh-independent values but might be helpful?

Comment: ah! this is very close. but yes being able to rely on less dense mesh would certainly be helpful. but I don't know if that's possible.